# A question on the zeros involving the equation containing exponential factor

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I recently encounter a puzzle that: how to show that for any constant $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4 \in \mathbb{R}$ the equation 
$$c_1 e^t+c_2e^{-t}+c_3 e^{\alpha t}+c_4 e^{-\alpha t}=0$$
has at most only one zero in the interval $(0,1)$, where $\alpha $ is a fixed positive absolute constant.

If any expert here has some heuristic please give a guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a plot of the function
$$f(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,\alpha,t)=c_1 e^t + c_2 e^{-t} +c_3 e^{\alpha t}+c_4 e^{-\alpha t}$$
as a function of $t$ for $c_1=1$, $c_2=1.93$, $c_3=-2.75$, $c_4=-0.09$, $\alpha=0.075$, with two zeros in the interval $0<t<1$:

[image]

So I would conclude the statement about there being at most 1 zero is false.

Comment: It would be instructive if you told how you came up with those precise values for the $c_i$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: there is nothing special about these values; I just varied the parameters, looked at the plot, and stopped when I found a set with two zero-crossings of the curve; I'm sure there are many other combinations of parameters that would do.

Comment: @AlexM. and Carlo Beenakker  Thanks for sharing your comments.